# using python selenium IE11, python(jupyter notebook) finds compeletly different element of HTML

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-crawler, internet-explorer-11

I am building a crawling code on a web page running only on IE11.

My problem is that python selenium,`selenium.webdriver.Ie`, find completely different element of HTML

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='1']")
```

I look for element which text is 1 on the calendar and `element.text`'s output is also 1 in `juypter notebook` like picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAJIx.png) (I can't be embedded because I'm a Newbie. I'm sorry.)

But if i operate element.click() in browser(driver, HTML),18 is clicked in browser.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6zYB.png)
Why did my code operate like this?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: Thanks for advise!
Did you say that I need to add HTML to tag?

Comment: Add the HTML part you expect to find, and the HTML part you actually find. That could help spotting the problem

Comment: Thank you for advise ! I added a picture to help understand. but i'm newbie, i could add only link to picture.

Comment: Have you tried adding specific tags in the selector? Something like this: `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='1']") `. If possible, could you provide sample code of the HTML Table element or the link to this webpage so that we can reproduce the problem? Thank you for your understanding.